# Select a textbox in PPT and export the data to an excel file

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm new to coding and trying to write a code to export the data from a selected textbox in powerpoint to an excel file. I want the program to ask the user to select a textbox and then export the data in this textbox to an excel file. Any leads or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this and try to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First things first, it would be easier for you to detect if a textbox is selected and ask the user to do so if not because the "ask a user to select a textbox" implies the use of a custom form that must be set to modeless so that it can remain open while the user interacts with the presentation.

So, assuming this is ok, this will get you going:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyTextBoxTextToExcel()
  Dim oShp As Shape
  With ActiveWindow.Selection
    ' If text is selected, select the parent shape (note : you'll need to adjust for Notes pane)
    If .Type = ppSelectionText Then .ShapeRange(1).Select
    ' If selection isn't a shape, help the user
    If Not .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then GoTo SelectMsg
    ' If more than one shape selected, help the user
    If Not .ShapeRange.Count = 1 Then GoTo SelectMsg
    ' If the shape doesn't have a textframe, help the user
    If Not .ShapeRange(1).HasTextFrame Then GoTo SelectMsg
    ' If the shape doesn't have any text, help the user
    If .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "" Then GoTo SelectMsg
    ' If all checks are ok, set a reference to the shape
    Set oShp = .ShapeRange(1)
  End With

  Dim myText As String
  myText = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

  ' Create an instance of Excel, using late binding to avoid reference library compatibility issues
  ' You can add a refernece to Microsoft Excel under Tools / References in order to use Intellisence during developemnt
  ' and then switch back to late binding for deployment.
  Dim oExcel As Object ' Use "As Excel.Application" when usign Early Binding
  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  ' Create a new workbook
  Dim oWB As Object ' Use "As Workbook" when using Early Binding
  Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

  oExcel.Visible = True

  ' Copy the text to a cell in the first sheet of the workbook
  oWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = myText

  ' Clean up
  Set oExcel = Nothing: Set oWB = Nothing
  Exit Sub

SelectMsg:
  MsgBox "Please select a single shape containing some text first.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Macro by http://youpresent.co.uk/"
End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this code is designed to run in the PowerPoint VBE.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I want the program to flow this was 
1. Ask the user to one-by-one click two textboxs (say Title of slide and sources of information)
2. Save the the format of these textboxes somewhere
3. Run the program in other slides to identify the above saved format textboxes and extract the information in these textboxes (in other slides) to an excel
Assumption: All the slides have title and sources in the same format

Comment: This is a different question. Your original questions states "ask the user to select a textbox and then export the data in this textbox to an excel file" and the answer I have provided does what you asked for. The new statement of needs which includes "Ask the user to one-by-one click two textboxs" requires a very different approach.